# QT multiple definitions

Tags: c++, qt, qwidget, multiple-definition-error

I've been trying to solve this issue and nothing seems to work, tryed clean the project, run qmake, made sure there was no recursive includes between files, but still showing the error.

Also there is not any function body on .h files, everything is on .cpp files. Using #ifndef #define.

Also have another QWindow class almost the same (in structure, not names) but that one works fine.

The errors appear only in this class but in all functions, don't know what could be causing the error.

Here's the code:

rlwindow.h

```
#ifndef RLWINDOW_H
#define RLWINDOW_H

#include <QWidget>
#include <QString>
#include <string.h>

#include "Utilities.h"
//#include "fmanager.h"


namespace Ui {class rlWindow;}


class rlWindow : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit rlWindow(bool login, QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~rlWindow();

private slots:
    void on_ContinueButton_clicked();

private:
    Ui::rlWindow *ui;
    //fmanager *Manager;
    pair<string> UserData;
    bool LoR; // True = Login / False = Register

};

#endif // RLWINDOW_H
```

rlwindow.cpp

```
#include "rlwindow.h"
#include "ui_rlwindow.h"

rlWindow::rlWindow(bool login, QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent), ui(new Ui::rlWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    //Manager = new fmanager("Data.txt");
    LoR = login;

    if(LoR){
        ui->TitleLabel->setText("Ingresar");
        ui->ContinueButton->setText("Ingresar");
    }
    else{
        ui->TitleLabel->setText("Registro");
        ui->ContinueButton->setText("Registrar");
    }
}

rlWindow::~rlWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void rlWindow::on_ContinueButton_clicked()
{/*
    UserData.first = ui->UserNameForm->text().toStdString();
    UserData.second = ui->UserPassForm->text().toStdString();

    if(LoR){
        for(uint i = 0; Manager->Data().size() > i; i++){

            if(Manager->Data()[i][0] == UserData.first && Manager->Data()[i][1] == UserData.second){

            }

        }
    }
    else{
        bool aux = false;
        for(uint i = 0; Manager->Data().size() > i; i++){

            if(Manager->Data()[i][0] == UserData.first){
                aux = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(!aux)
            Manager->addItem(UserData.first, UserData.second);
    }
*/
}
```

[image]

Comment: show the complete error messages...

Comment: @eyllanesc added the link to the image with the errors.

Comment: The problem is that you have 2 classes with the same name: `class rlWindow : public QWidget` and   `Ui::rlWindow *ui;`

Comment: For example, if you review the `ui_rlwindow.h` file generated by the uic and you will see that the setupUi method receives an object of the same class as an argument.

Comment: Ohhh then should i rename the class or something or what should i do? @eyllanesc

Comment: I don't know how you created the classes but generally the classes generated by uic use the Ui prefix to avoid these problems, for example MainWindow with Ui_MainWindow, Dialog with Ui_Dialog and Form with Ui_Form

Comment: Yes, i saw the ui_rlwindow.h and it is like that, also i just use the default ui class for that, so i dont know how or when it went all wrong :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to delete all the class files (.cpp, .h, .ui) and redo it again but with different name (class name)